# How to create custom rules for PMD Apex static code analyzer?

Tags: apex, pmd

How can I create custom rules for PMD? For example, if I want to create a rule to say '*all code should be in allman style and therefore, any line with { should be the only character on the line'*, how can I do this?

I have the same questions as are asked on this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000g8SbQAI. I saw this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LwqhRj_8ek - and I can see the designer.bat file, although I don't see a UI appear. But even so, it doesn't tell me how I can create a custom rule specifically.

Does anyone have a step by step process on how to create a new rule for Apex PMD?

Thanks

Comment: I recall I have come across some step by step articles before.

This one is from the author Robert. Does it help?
https://github.com/rsoesemann/codeclimate-apexmetrics/wiki/add-a-new-rule-for-apex-pmd